# mysql make select value default to positive integer 

Tags: mysql, select

`num_daysopen` returns how many days since dateopened.
Days left returns how many days a user has to close something (they have upto 28 days from dateopened).   If its longer than 28 days `days_left` needs to default to 0 not -5 or -15 etc.

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)) AS num_daysopen,
  (28 - DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened))) as days_left
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GREATEST().

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)) AS num_daysopen,
  GREATEST(0,(28 - DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), DATE(dateopened)))) as days_left
FROM table
```